# Reference DbContext in new MVC Controller that has been added to Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, razor-pages

I had a pure .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages application with no MVC modules.
Then I added a Controller folder, a View folder, and used the Models folder I already had.

I am trying to reference my database in the new Controller but I can't seem to get the syntax. 
Here is my working Courses Page .cs file with the working DbContext at the top:

```
namespace OESAC.Pages.Courses
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public readonly MyDbContext _context;
        public IndexModel(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

Below is the top of my MVC Controller code which I thought I had figured out but I get an error.

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
_configuration was null.*

The last 2 lines is where I get the error (save changes). The regular data driven Razor Pages work with db.SaveChanges because I have the syntax correct for declaring _context.

```
namespace OESAC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        MyDbContext db = new  MyDbContext();


 public ActionResult StartTransaction(string oesacID, string fee)
        {
            var model = new Models.PayPalTransactions();

            string strToday = DateTime.Today.ToString();

            model.TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse(strToday);
            model.RecordCreated = DateTime.Parse(strToday);
            model.CourseID = 4444;
            model.SponsorID = 3333;
            model.AmountCharged = 1;

            //INSERT TRANSACTION ROW IN TRANSACTION TABLE

           db.PayPalTransactions.Add(model);
           db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: .Net core use DI, u can try to registe dbContext in StartUp class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependency injection in controllers too.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you cdev. You made my day. I have spent almost a week trying to get PayPal to work with Razor Pages. Finally added Controller and Views and used some older MVC code. 
It worked like a charm, right off the bat, got to Sandbox and back, but now values returned, but that is another story for another bedtime. Thank you!!!